# Powershell: add group to all OU Permissions

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

how is it possible to add the Group "administrator" to all OUs Permission entries with fullcontrol by powershell?

quest active roles can be used.

i failed on my try:

```
$test=Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -like "*"' -searchscope onelevel | FT Name | ForEach-Object{ Add-QADPermission -"$test" -Account "administrators"  -ApplyTo ChildObjects -Rights genericall}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -like "*"' -searchscope onelevel | Select -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName | ForEach-Object{ Add-QADPermission "$_" -Account 'domainName\administrator' -Rights 'GenericAll' -ApplyTo 'ChildObjects'}
```

That should get all OUs in the root of the domain, and then for each OU it will add the administrator group to all child objects and anything that descends from them. If you want to include the first level OUs you will want to probably want to change 'ChildObjects' to 'All'.

If you have any issues or questions please leave a comment.

Comment: Error appears: WARNING: Can't lookup object for identity: @{DistinguishedName=OU=testOU,DC=test,DC=local}